# Fetching jenkins build status from python script

Tags: python, jenkins

I am trying to fetch status of all the builds for all my jobs.I have written a script it takes way too much time to execute.Is there anyway I can optimize the script? Any help will be appreciated.

```
 def jenkinsconn():
        server = jenkins.Jenkins('server',username=username,password=password)
        jobs = server.get_jobs()
        job_name_list=[]
        build_number_list=[]
        build_info_list=[]
        status_list_dict={}
        success=0
        failure=0
        unstable=0
        aborted=0
        #print dir(server)
        for i in range(len(jobs)):
                job_name=jobs[i]['name']
                job_name_list.append(job_name)
        for i in range(len(job_name_list)):
                job_info=server.get_job_info(job_name_list[i])
        lastbuilt=job_info['lastSuccessfulBuild']
                if lastbuilt:
                    b_number=job_info['lastSuccessfulBuild']['number']
                    build_number_list.append(b_number)
            build_zipped=zip(job_name_list,build_number_list)
    for i ,j in build_zipped:
                success=0
                failure=0
                unstable=0
                aborted=0
                for k in range(j):        
                            build_info=server.get_build_info(i,k+1)
                            build_info_list.append(build_info)
                            status=build_info['result']
                            if status=="SUCCESS":
                                    success+=1
                            elif status=="FAILURE":
                                    failure+=1
                            elif status=="UNSTABLE":
                                    unstable+=1
                            else:
                                    aborted+=1
                            statuscount=[success,failure,unstable,aborted]
                            status_list_dict[i]=statuscount
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need the number of builds succeeding, failing, etc. then you can make do with one request per job, rather than a request per build like it looks like your code is doing. I can't find an method in the python-jenkins module to do this, but you can do it yourself with the Jenkins API.

Eg:

```
try:                 # Python 3
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    from urllib.parse import quote
except ImportError:  # Python 2
    from urllib2 import urlopen, quote

import json
import contextlib

status_list_dict = {}
with contextlib.closing(
    urlopen("http://HOST_NAME:8080/api/json")
) as job_list_response:
    job_list = json.load(job_list_response)["jobs"]

for job in job_list:
    status_counts = [0,0,0,0]

    with contextlib.closing(
        urlopen(
            "http://HOST_NAME:8080/job/{job_name}/api/json?tree=allBuilds[result]".format(
                job_name=quote(job["name"])
            )
        )
    ) as build_list_response:
        build_list = json.load(build_list_response)["allBuilds"]

        for build_data in build_list:
            if build_data["result"] == "SUCCESS":
                status_counts[0] += 1
            elif build_data["result"] == "FAILURE":
                status_counts[1] += 1
            elif build_data["result"] == "UNSTABLE":
                status_counts[2] += 1
            elif build_data["result"] == "ABORTED":
                status_counts[3] += 1

     status_list_dict[job["name"]] = status_counts
```

Comment: If someone searching for way to do this via requests library and with authentication - https://github.com/squadcastHQ/Integration-scripts/blob/master/jenkins/send-data-to-squadcast.py